# Программа для массовой замены текста и html тегов

Tags: php, python, linux, windows, str-replace

Есть статичная копия многостраничного сайта.  Нужно массово заменить текст внутри html. К примеру, выкинуть аналитику или сменить везде текст в менюшке. С помощью какой программы можно это сделать?

**notepad не подходит** для многострочной замены
**ВК replaceem тоже не подходит** слишком криво собран и после каждой замены нужно перезапускать приложение

Какие знаете аналогичные приложения/библиотеки? Если второе, то лучше с примерами, либо если хорошая api с примерами, то ссылку на api

Спасибо!

Comment: Любая нормальная ide может заменять тексты

Comment: @dIm0n К примеру?

Comment: Ну по вашим тегам PhpStorm, PyCharm, редактор notepad++ тоже вроде может

Comment: Atom, VisualStudio Code и прочее, прочее...

Comment: @dIm0n У меня многострочная замена на многострочную. PhpStrorm не учитывает переход на новую строку. У notepad строка ввода ограничена по длинне + нельзя вставить несколько строк кода для замены.

Comment: @Tip так а как вы делаете замену? С помощью регулярного выражения? Приведите его тогда в вопросе вместе с примерами текстов, поможем отладить. Если срабатывают ограничения по длине, то, наверное, просто вставляете огромный текст в in и out. Скорее всего, так делать не надо, но если хотите, то в том же питоне это метод `replace()`. Есть специальные парсеры для html также в обоих языках

Comment: @Tip, PhpStorm учитывает многострочную замену. Много раз уже этим пользовался.

Comment: @dIm0n Без регулярок.Просто какую-то строку нужно всегда заменить. На питоне не пишу, поэтому хз как нормальный скрипт для замены текста из in на out сделать

Comment: @VenZell Всегда считал иначе. Завтра попробую, спасибо

Comment: @Tip перенос строки в html не важен. выдели текст - скопируй в буфер и заменяй

Answer (score 0):

> Нужно массово заменить текст внутри html.

Специально для решения таких задач существуют две утилиты:

1. sed - Пакетный редактор
2. awk - Обработка текста по шаблонам

Обе они могут вести обработку в пакетном режиме. Обе выполняют некоторые корректировки текстовых файлов. Для обоих надо написать некую (м.б. - совсем крохотную) "программу" обработки текста.

Первая - совсем простая. Вторая - посложнее, но гибче.

Comment: Обрабатывать XML c помощью регулярных выражений -- это сознательно делать диверсию и создать проблемы на ровном месте. И не надо людей в заблуждение вводить - эти инструменты для текста, а не специализированных структур данных.